# I want to show details to the right side of screen after clicking an item on left, flutter

Tags: flutter, web-applications

[I want to do something like this][1]

I want to show details to the right side of screen after clicking an item on left for my web app
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P4Oq.png

```
body:child:Row[ 
TabBarView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        children: [
                          OngoingOrder(),//listview inside each view
                          CompletedOrder(),
                          CancelledOrder(),
                        ]),
                  ),
                   ShowOrder(
                        //rightside of page
                      )
                ]),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

please post your existing code to understand
what logic you have performed.
If you are using any state management tool then please also mention that.

```
pseudocode: (flutter basic without any state management)

1)create a null Object for the right side 
2)perform a null check to show the default demo message "Select An Order to see"
3)when user select an Order, populate the created object with the selected data and call setState((){})
```